# Issues with Adding 1 month to a Unix time stamp

Tags: php

For some reason, I cannot get strtotime('+1 month) to work. Here is my code;

```
$Date   = $_REQUEST['date']; //This is a unix time stamp
$Start  = $_REQUEST['start']; //This is a unix time stamp
$End    = $_REQUEST['end']; //This is a unix time stamp
```

to add a month onto my dates;

```
$monStart =strtotime('+1 month', $Start);
$monEnd   =strtotime('+1 month', $End);
$monDate  =strtotime('+1 month', $Date);
```

then to show my changed dates;

```
$vEnd = date('m/d/Y', $monEnd);
$vStart = date('m/d/Y', $monStart);
$vDate = date('m/d/Y', $monDate);
```

The problem that I have is that the supplied dates;

```
$Date = 1/31/2013
$Start = 1/01/2013
$End = 1/31/2013
```

Return;

```
$vDate = 3/03/2013
$vStart = 2/01/2013 //Only correct one
$vEnd = 3/03/2013
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: What are the expected values?

Comment: $vDate = 2/28/2013, $VStart is corrtct, and $vEnd = 2/28/2013

Comment: @ipfreelly what's the issue. What output do you want

Comment: @Sabari, I'm trying to get the next month, this is for an invoice. So the invoice's date is 1/31/2013, the start of the invoice is 1/1/2013 and the end is 1/31/2013. I added a button to increase the dates by one month but you can see the results that I am getting.

Comment: If you're sure that the end date is the end of the month, you might be better off just iterating over the end-dates of the month, rather than trying to add one month to the date.

Comment: The problem is that not all invoices fall on the end of the month, they can also fall on the second to the last day of the month

Comment: PHP thinks '1/31/2013 + 1 month' is 2/31/2013, which rolls over to Mar 3. If you need the last day of the month, you can use 'last day +1 month'. If it needs to be the same day but shifted, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2557146/1955291

Comment: @ipfreelly check my answer, Hope that helps you

Comment: I'll work on it in the morning, got to take take care of a crying new born, thanks everyone!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's jumping to March because today is 31sth Jan, and adding a month gives 31st Feb, which doesn't exist, so it's moving to the next valid date. This is a PHP bug. You can get more info on that at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44073

You can try with `DateTime` to over come this scenario. You can use this function for your requirement

```
function add_month($date_value, $months, $format = 'm/d/Y') {
    $date = new DateTime($date_value);
    $start_day = $date->format('j');

    $date->modify("+{$months} month");
    $end_day = $date->format('j');

    if ($start_day != $end_day)
        $date->modify('last day of last month');

    return $date->format($format);
}
```

Now you can call :

```
$vEnd = add_month($monEnd, 1);
$vStart = add_month($monStart, 1);
$vDate = add_month($monDate, 1);
```

This will give you :

```
$vDate = '02/28/2013';
$vStart = '02/01/2013';
$vEnd = '02/28/2013';
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) is *much* better for handling date math as it account for things like days in the month:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-02-01');
$dt->modify('+1 month');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8guw1h)

Since you're using timestamps it might look like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$_REQUEST['start']);
$dt->modify('+1 month');
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: sorry, but I am very new to this. so I've tried;                                                                 $monStart =new DateTime($Start);
   $monStart->modify('+1 month');
   echo $monStart->format('Y-m-d'); and all i recieve is errors

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (1356998400) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character' in C:\wamp\www\Invoices\MiddlePane.php on line 11